8 month old roof - area behind gutter seems open and back roof is bubbling / lifting
Just had my roof completely replaced in December - down to bare wood / any problem boards replaced / etc. Been having humidity problems in the house and have had HVAC serviced (fine) + checked attic fan (brand new and on a humidistat / working well).
Cleaning the gutters today and saw that this area behind the gutter seems open / exposed. Is there something that should be covering this? (don't want to seem dumb when I call the roofer - novice homeowner)
Also, the back / three seasons room roof on the house seems to now be lifting / bubbling. This was a problem area before the roof was replaced - specifically asked for this area to be repaired. Any idea what would be causing this?
They added a ridge vent in that room and the peak of the rest of the house so would expect it to vent humidity (but could be wrong / dumb - any advice is appreciated)



There should be a flashing where the two levels of shingles intersect.
